# How to add placeholder in dropdown list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Hi I have dropdown list code I want to add placeholder there how I can add?

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlyear" runat="server" >
                     <asp:ListItem >Experience</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>Fresher</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to show like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it on HTML alone, you'd need Html + jQuery to achieve this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlyear" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Experience</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Fresher</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

After this, you need your jQuery to do the magic by removing and re attaching your placeholder.

```
<script>
var isChanged = false;
$(function () {
    $('#ddlyear').focusin(function () {
        if (!isChanged) {
// this removes the first item which is your placeholder if it is never changed
            $(this).find('option:first').remove();
        }
    });
    $('#ddlyear').change(function () {
// this marks the selection to have changed
        isChanged = true;
    });
    $('#ddlyear').focusout(function () {
        if (!isChanged) {
// if the control loses focus and there is no change in selection, return the first item
            $(this).prepend('<option selected="selected" value="0">Experience</option>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Take note that you need jQuery to use this, just install it as a nuget package or download it manually and add a declaration in your aspx.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
// Sample only, you can place it in any location or use any version
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just do this:

```
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlyear" runat="server" >
                     <asp:ListItem selected hidden>Experience</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>Fresher</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

The `selected` makes it the default, while `hidden` prevents it to be visible on the expanded list.

It's the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

@amit

> Brother try this....

```
<select placeholder="select your beverage">
<option value="" default="" selected="">select your beverage</option>
<option value="tea">Tea</option>
<option value="coffee">Coffee</option>
<option value="soda">Soda</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The placeholder attribute wont work, it only shows because of the first option you declared.

Comment: It's the "selected", you can add "hidden" to not make it appear in the list

Answer (score 0):

In many cases it would be acceptable to have an empty or dummy item as the first item. 'Empty' means that the value is empty, the text can be anything you want.

So like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlyear" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Experience">Experience</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Fresher">Fresher</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```